# Why there are specific number of layers with same depth in any CNN architecture?

Tags: cnn

why each architecture have specific number of layers with same depth

like vgg had 2 with 64 depth and 2 with 128d and 4 layers

same with ResNet and 34 layer plain like 6 layers with depth of 64 and 8 layers with depth 128.

and why depth increasing by last depth *2 ?

is there is way or equation to decide number of layers with each depth ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equation or theory to decide the number of layers at each depth in a neural network. The most common technique is trail and error. Cross validation is one way to do systematic search.

Generally, more layers are added until performance stops improving.